# The program is aborting with unexpected output, counting unreachable nodes in graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I just implemented a dfs algorithm and thought of trying a question. The question is as follows:

**Input Format**

The first line consists of a 2 integers N and M denoting the number of nodes and edges in this graph. The next M lines consist of 2 integers a and b denoting an undirected edge between node a and b. The next line consists of a single integer x denoting the index of the head node.

***Output Format *:****

You need to print a single integer denoting the number of nodes that are unreachable from the given head node.

**The test case input is as follows:**

```
10 10
8 1
8 3
7 4
7 5
2 6
10 7
2 8
10 9
2 10
5 10
2
```

[test case and constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV9uo.png)

Output for this case is :

```
0
```

The code I wrote:

```
        #include<iostream>
    #include<list>
    #include<queue>
    using namespace std;
    int mycount = 0;
    //Adj List Implementation for Integer Nodes
    class Graph {
    private:
        int V;
        
        //Array of Linked Lists of size V, V LL's are there
        list<int>* adjList;
        int* visited;
    
    public:
        Graph(int v) {
            V = v;
           
            adjList = new list<int>[V];
            visited = new int[V] { 0 };
        }
        void addEdge(int u, int v, bool bidir = true)
        {
            adjList[u].push_back(v);
            if (bidir) {
                adjList[v].push_back(u);
            }
        }
    
    
        int dfs(int vertex)
        {
            visited[vertex] = true;
            mycount++;
    
            for (auto node : adjList[vertex]) {
                if (!visited[node]) {
                    dfs(node);
                }
    
            }
            return mycount;
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    };
    
    
    
    int main() {
        //taking input of number of nodes and edges
        int inputNode, inputEdge;
        cin >> inputNode >> inputEdge;

    //graph object
        Graph g(inputNode);
//taking input
        for (int i = 0; i < inputEdge; i++) {
            int u, v;
            cin >> u >> v;
            g.addEdge(u, v);
        }
        int index;
        cin >> index;
        //run the dfs on index
        int reachabeNodes = g.dfs(index);
    
        cout << inputNode - reachabeNodes;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I saw other codes after my code didn't execute but found them to use almost the same logic as mine,

- I have declared a global **mycount** variable and it's incremented every time DFS is called so that it stores the number of edges that are connected and can be visited.
- Next, I print the subtraction of **total node given in input - mycount**
  **Please help me where I am going wrong in the solution.**

Comment: Apart from using dynamically created lists/rar arrays, your core issue is the the data you are taking is 1 based but c++ uses 0 based indices. `g.addEdge(u-1, v-1);`

Comment: I have made your change from inserting (u-1,v-1)  but still the program is crashing.

Comment: Here's the link to the question page https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/tutorial/#c240293

Comment: Thats because you've broken it attempting to make Christophers changes. Don't randomly edit questions with new code as answers/comments then don't make sense.

Comment: OMG! It worked. Thank you so much. So could you please explain me in a little detail why this worked so that I don't repeat the same mistake in future. So I used initial code and swapping addEdge(u,v) with addEdge(u-1,v-1)

Comment: You are told there are 10 edges. You create an array of 10 items. Those items have valid indices 0 to 9 as C and C++ use _0 based indexing_. When later you are told 10<-> 10 has an edge, you try to access index 10 of your array which doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a vector of lists, not a pointer to an array of lists, and a vector instead of an array.

Comment: I changed the array to vector, but I don't know how to implement it using a list instead a pointer to list. Even after converting array to vector, I am getting the same error.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It should be a comment instead.

Comment: If a program crashes and does raw allocations, it is the first thing to fix.

Comment: I've changed as you suggested @ChristopherYeleighton. Please take a look at edits.

Comment: Also here is the link to actual problem https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/tutorial/#c240293

Comment: @SonnyPark your changes make no sense. `adjList[V]` just access element `V` of an empty array. Change to `adjList.resize(V)` and the same with visited. See my comment for your actual issue.

Comment: Rather use a member constructor: V (v), adjList (v) etc.

Comment: thank you @ChristopherYeleighton for your time, it solved after changing addEdge(u,v) with addEdge(u-1,v-1);